# Netsuite How to create a form record in transaction sublist

Tags: netsuite

How could I create a form record in transaction sublist like the red box in the screenshot?

[image]

Comment: More detail, please!

Comment: I want to create a sublist like the image that I can increase the multiple employee's records , name , phone and more informations.
Thanks.